# Crystal reports, selecting latest apearence of group in table

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am new in this Crystal Reports thing and I have problem, since my coworker usually doing this stuff is sick at home I need to figure it out my self. I have 2 tables.

First is like this:

`Article.ID    Article.name Article.buyingprice
1              aa           2.00
2              bb           1.00
3              cc           3.50
4              dd           4.20
5              ee           2.00`

And second is like this:

`Income.ID Income.article  Income.date  Income.number Income.quantity
1          2               79100        P1            2.00
2          1               79100        P1            3.00
3          4               79101        P2            2.00
4          3               79101        P2            1.00
5          1               79101        P2            4.00
6          5               79101        P2            1.00
7          2               79103        P3            15.00`

What I need is formula for selecting Income.quantity from the latest Income document. For example for article aa it will be 4.00 and for article bb it will be 15. Please save my job folks :)

Report is grouped by article.name.

Comment: If you need only show it in article group footer, then set order to invoice date and display not summary result, but field itself - it evaluates to latest value. If you need to perform some operations with it (or display not in group footer), then you can either use sql view to calculate it (my preference) or play with crystal functions (you can compare any field values to previos and next records etc). Sorry no complete answer here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your solution you can make a group in Crystal report

1. Add group on ArticleId sort by ascending
2. Add One more group on IncomeId sort by descending
3. Now Suppress all Group headers and footer
4. open section expert , set formula below
5. Formula: `if(previous({Command.Aritcle.ID}) = {Command.Aritcle.ID}) then true else false;`

Answer (score 0):

```
This Can Be Achieved in SQl server by using CTE

BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #Article (ID INT ,name NVARCHAR(20),buyingprice Decimal (15,2))

CREATE TABLE #Income (ID INT ,article INT,DATE nvarchar(50),number nvarchar(20),quantity Decimal (15,2))

insert into #Article
SELECT 1,'aa',2.00 union all
SELECT 2,'bb',1.00 union all
SELECT 3,'cc',3.50 union all
SELECT 4,'dd',4.20 union all
SELECT 5,'ee',2.00


insert into #Income
select 1,2,'79100','P1',2.00   union all
select 2,1,'79100','P1' ,3.00  union all
select 3,4,'79101','P2',2.00   union all
select 4,3,'79101','P2',1.00  union all
select 5,1,'79101','P2',4.00 union all
select 6,5,'79101','P2',1.00 union all
select 7,2,'79103','P3',15.00

go
with CTE as
    (   select A.ID,name,b.date, B.quantity,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  a.ID,name ORDER BY  a.ID,name ) AS Rn
        FROM #Article A inner JOIN #Income B ON A.ID=B.article

    )
SELECT a.ID,a.date,a.name, a.quantity 
FROM CTE a 
WHERE a.Rn= (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM cte b)



ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: I guess you didn't understood me, I need formula that will print latest income quantity for article. I already have those tables, I have report but when I tried to create formula 'if {income.date} =maximum({income.date}, {article.name}) than income.quantity' but it selects last document even if there was no income for this article

Comment: @PrzemyslawSidor  Have you RUN The query and check I had put the Logic to Get The latest report as per your Information That was the sample data given by you to check and i'm getting the desired output you are Looking for

Comment: I belive u still don't understand. I don't need sql query, I need crystal reports formula. For sql query yours idea is good, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSidor I know you are looking for formula to achieve this in crystal report but I try this from sql query